# How to add Sub DropDown Menus

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

I am a beginner in HTML and need some help from you guys

I want to add Sub DropDown menus, In Tutorials Dropdown menu i have three main dropdown menus, namely: HTML5, CSS, JQuery

Now i would like to show two more sub menus namely : Downloads and Videos under HTML 5 Dropdown menu

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right navbar-main-collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="active"><a href="#intro">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#service">Service</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Tutorials<b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">HTML 5</a></li>
      <!-- here i would like to show two sub dropdown menus, first Downlo ads and second Videos  --> 
    <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">JQuery</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: i have written above script

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use another dropdown with SelectedIndexChanged event which fires the second dropdownlist.Something like this :

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="224px"
    AutoPostBack="True" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server"
    onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList> 


protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//Load DropDownList2

}
```

Since you havent posted your code,couldnt help you more.